# Firebase UI Auth 2.0.1 showing multiple welcome back password prompt screens

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm using Firebase ui in my android app. I recently updated to Firebase UI version 2.0.1.  After updating, when a user logs in with email/password provider (with an account that has already been logged in before), the auth flow opens up 2 welcome back password prompt screens.

1. user types in email address and hits next.
2. welcome back screen shows. (except there are 2 welcome back screens one on top of the other
3. user enters password in welcome back screen and hits sign in
4. first welcome back screen closes and the 2nd one shows
5. user has to enter password in 2nd welcome back screen.

I switched back to firebase ui 1.2.0 and this issue goes away.

So is this a bug in 2.0.1? anyone else seeing this issue or similar? 
thanks

Answer (score 3):

I am answering my own question in case someone else comes across this ridiculous issue.
I figured out the issue only happens in the android emulator and with firebase ui version 2.0.1.
With version 2.0.1 the auth ui login flow allows you to hit enter on your computer's physical keyboard instead of requiring you to click on the NEXT button on the emulator's screen. Version 1.2.0 does not allow this, it requires you to click.
Anyway if you hit enter on your keyboard after entering the email address instead of clicking NEXT, then you will get 2 welcome back screens instead of 1.
Of course this is not an issue when testing on a real phone. So I guess my lesson is -always test issues on a real phone...

Comment: please report this as a bug to firebase

Answer (score 3):

*One of the FirebaseUI maintainers here.*

#### New answer:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/869#issuecomment-326655108

> Ok so I lied.  I'm implementing keyboard shortcuts in my app and I have a much better understanding of the `KeyEvent` stuff now. Turns out we *were* getting two events, one for the down event and one for the up event. On top of that, if you hold the key, it will continually call `onKeyDown`. Ouch!  Not sure why I didn't notice this behavior on ChromeBooks, maybe they have a compatibility mode or something.

#### Old answer:

Someone else filed this bug and you can read [my response](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/869#issuecomment-323263300), although I believe you are correct in assuming it only occurs when using an emulator. I haven't been able to reproduce it on a ChromeBook and as you mentioned, the bug doesn't occur on real phones either. (In addition, if you click the enter button on the virtual keyboard, you'll notice that the bug doesn't occur either.)

Comment: Yes that describes the issue exactly as I remember it. I find myself using a real phone more often now.. thanks